# login vs signup with facebook using iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, appdelegate

In my app, the signup with Facebook process flow goes like this:

```
signup with Facebook -> setup profile image and username -> home screen
```

…and the login with Facebook process flow goes like this:

```
login with Facebook -> home screen
```

However in the tutorial provided by Facebook, there's only 1 function which is login. how can I differentiate the process?
I looked at the function documentation of

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:]
```

It says that the function can run asynchronously (the login UI is not shown even when `allowLoginUI` is set to YES, therefore the `completionHandler` is called) or synchronously (the login UI is shown, and then redirect to my app, therefore calling the method `- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error` in the AppDelegate)

So, my question is, IF the method `sessionStateChanged` is called by my signup function or login function, how can I differentiate them, so that I can navigate to appropriate screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a flag, stored in `NSUserDefault`. If the user click FBSignup, I set the flag to `@"fbSignup"` else, if the user click FBLogin, I set the flag to `@"fbLogin"`. On the method `- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error` I just check the flag whether it is `@"fbSignup"` or `@"fbLogin"`

Comment: Any chance you can post an example of some of your code?